# HTA Window Resizing Vertical Only

Tags: javascript, html, vbscript, hta

I would like to know if HTA is capable of resizing only in veritical direction. (i.e. width stays unchange) Ideally I want my window to be exactly the way of Command Prompt works (The width won't extend but height could). Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is VB but principals are similar. An event fires if a window is resized horizontally. HTAs are internet explorer windows.

**Syntax**

```
Private Sub object_WindowSetWidth( _
    ByVal nWidth As Long)
```

**Parameters**

**object**

Object expression that resolves to the WebBrowser object.

**nWidth**

Long that specifies the width of the WebBrowser control. 
Error Codes

No return value.

**Remarks**

The WindowSetWidth event is fired when the width of a window is changed, using the Width property.

Comment: Thank you! I will try this later!

Comment: Remember if you override it you will get an event for your own actions so check `nWidth` to see if you need to do anything.